# Using math and grep

Tags: regex, grep

I need to find the number of invalid email addresses in a file, basically any line that contains "@" but is not in the correct format.
I am using this to count the number of valid email addresses:

```
 grep -Ei '[A-Z0-9.-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{3}' $1 | wc -l
```

and this to calculate how many lines contain @:

```
grep -E '@' $1 | wc -l
```

is there a way I can possibly subtract the number of lines that contain @ anywhere and the number of valid emails before printing with wc -l?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` has `-c` option to just print the occurrences, you should leverage that instead  of spawning another process and an anonymous pipe:

```
grep -c '<pattern>' file.txt
```

To subtract the counts from two searches, you can can directly subtract them leveraging command substitution:

```
echo $(( $(grep -c '<pattern_1>' file.txt) - $(grep -c '<pattern_2>' file.txt) ))
```

If you fancy, you can use two variables as well:

```
count_1=$(grep -c '<pattern_1>' file.txt)
count_2=$(grep -c '<pattern_2>' file.txt)
echo $(( count_1 - count_2 ))
```